# How to refere same schema as a type in moonsoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a comment list Objects which stores the comments and whoever replies to that comment it getting store in the children

```
{
    "_id": "5dbc479babc1c22683b73cf3",
    "comment": "wow .. this is awsome",
    "children": [
      {
        "_id": "5dbc481ec3bb512780ebda22",
        "comment": "second child",
        "children": [
          {
            "_id": "5dbc481ec3bb512780ebda22",
            "comment": "hi darling",
            "children": [],
            "user": {
              "_id": "5dbb81c8c597533bf4c38e75",
              "username": "arunkavale",
              "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/johnsmithagency/128.jpg"
            },
            "updatedDate": "2019-11-01T14:58:38.188Z",
            "createdDate": "2019-11-01T14:58:38.188Z"
          }
        ],
        "user": {
          "_id": "5dbb81c8c597533bf4c38e75",
          "username": "arunkavale",
          "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/johnsmithagency/128.jpg"
        },
        "updatedDate": "2019-11-01T14:58:38.188Z",
        "createdDate": "2019-11-01T14:58:38.188Z"
      },
      {
        "_id": "5dbc481ec3bb512780ebda22",
        "comment": "yep",
        "children": [],
        "user": {
          "_id": "5dbb81c8c597533bf4c38e75",
          "username": "arunkavale",
          "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/johnsmithagency/128.jpg"
        },
        "updatedDate": "2019-11-01T14:58:38.188Z",
        "createdDate": "2019-11-01T14:58:38.188Z"
      }
    ],
    "user": {
      "_id": "5dbb9683b44bfa2a3dce55bd",
      "username": "mayank",
      "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/alxndrustinov/128.jpg"
    },
    "createdDate": "2019-11-01T14:56:27.580Z",
    "updatedDate": "2019-11-01T14:58:38.188Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
```

and here is the schema which i have designed

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type:String
    },
    avatar:{
        type:String
    }
 });


 var ChildrenSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "comment":{
        type:String
    },
    parentId:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    },
    children:{
        type:[ChildrenSchema]
    },
    user:{
        type:UserSchema
    }
 },{timestamps: { createdAt: 'createdDate', updatedAt: 'updatedDate' }});






let CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user:{
        type:UserSchema,
    },
   "comment":{
       type:String
   },
   children:{
       type:[ChildrenSchema]
   }
},{timestamps: { createdAt: 'createdDate', updatedAt: 'updatedDate' }});


var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
module.exports = {Comment};
```

here I am trying to give children type as the same ChildrenSchema but it is not working it is throwing **{ CastError: Cast to embedded failed for value "{ comment: \'hi darling\',\n  children: [],\n  user:\n   { _id: \'5dbb81c8c597533bf4c38e75\',\n     username: \'arunkavale\',\n     avatar:\n      \'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/johnsmithagency/128.jpg\' } }" at path "children** error .. I am not getting how to do this .please help me in this

Answer (score 1):

Modify the way of defining Subdocuments array as below and give a try

```
   children:[ChildrenSchema]
```